# SimpleXml to string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Is there any function that makes string from PHP `SimpleXMLElement`?

Comment: What kind of string do you want?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use the [`SimpleXMLElement::asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) method to accomplish this:

```
$string = "<element><child>Hello World</child></element>";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

// The entire XML tree as a string:
// "<element><child>Hello World</child></element>"
$xml->asXML();

// Just the child node as a string:
// "<child>Hello World</child>"
$xml->child->asXML();
```

Comment: `$string = $xml->child->__toString();`

Comment: htmlspecialchars(  $xml->asXML() )  ?

Comment: but yo are left with the tags, what if you don't want the tags? other answers solve this problem

Comment: Don't use @LukeSnowden's method as this isn't supposed to be called directly. The actual correct answer is Nicolay77's answer which uses casting.

Answer (score 75):

You can use casting:

```
<?php

$string = "<element><child>Hello World</child></element>";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$text = (string)$xml->child;
```

$text will be 'Hello World'

Comment: Works for me because it doesn't put the tags in, thanks

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [`asXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asXML.php) method as:

```
<?php

// string to SimpleXMLElement
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

// make any changes.
....

// convert the SimpleXMLElement back to string.
$newString = $xml->asXML();
?>
```

Answer (score 17):

Actually asXML() converts the string into xml as it name says:

```
<id>5</id>
```

This will display normally on a web page but it will cause problems when you matching values with something else.

You may use strip_tags function to get real value of the field like:

```
$newString = strip_tags($xml->asXML());
```

PS: if you are working with integers or floating numbers, you need to convert it into integer with **intval()** or **floatval()**.

```
$newNumber = intval(strip_tags($xml->asXML()));
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `->child` to get a child element named *child*.

This element will contain the text of the *child* element.

But if you try `var_dump()` on that variable, you will see it is not actually a PHP string.

The easiest way around this is to perform a `strval(xml->child);`
That will convert it to an actual PHP string.

This is useful when debugging when looping your XML and using `var_dump()` to check the result.

So `$s = strval($xml->child);`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a function I wrote to solve this issue (assuming tag has no attributes). This function will keep HTML formatting in the node:

```
function getAsXMLContent($xmlElement)
{
  $content=$xmlElement->asXML();

  $end=strpos($content,'>');
  if ($end!==false)
  {
    $tag=substr($content, 1, $end-1);

    return str_replace(array('<'.$tag.'>', '</'.$tag.'>'), '', $content);
  }
  else
    return '';
}


$string = "<element><child>Hello World</child></element>";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

echo getAsXMLContent($xml->child); // prints Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can simply typecast:

```
// this is the value of my $xml
object(SimpleXMLElement)#10227 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "en"
}

$s = (string) $xml; // returns "en";
```

Comment: This is the kind of object you get for the description field of an RSS feed. It's counter-intuitive that it works, but it was the only solution here that gave me the string inside `$xmlitem->description`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Probably* depending on the XML feed you may/may not need to use `__toString()`; I had to use the `__toString()` otherwise it is returning the string inside an SimpleXMLElement.  Maybe I need to drill down the object further ...