# Save XML file after loaded in form and edit

Tags: php, xml

I created this PHP script that loads the contents of an XML file into a form, but I can't save it after modifying the fields.
I wanted to know if it was possible to do it, and how.
Thanks Mau.

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <?php
    if (file_exists('data/mess.xml')) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('indexdata/index_messages_en.xml');
        foreach ($xml->data as $el) {
            echo "<label for='{$el}'>{$el['name']}</label>
          <input name='{$el['name']}' value='{$el}'/><br>";
        }
    } else {
        exit('Failed to open');
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update">
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // method for save edited field in same xml file
    }
?>
```

My mess.xml file:

```
<?xmlversion = "1.0"encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <data name="project_title">
        <![CDATA[New Project]]></data>
    <data name="section_title">
        <![CDATA[ES000021903]]></data>
</project>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't save it"? Why can't you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you'll need to rewrite the file to keep the changes from one edit to the other.

Look at [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php) or [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.fopen.php).

Of course, you'll have to rewrite the entire XML, with tags and attributes. You can either do it in a simple string :

```
$myxml='
<?xmlversion = "1.0"encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <data name="project_title">
        <![CDATA['.$_POST['project_title'].']]></data>
    <data name="section_title">
        <![CDATA['.$_POST['section_title'].']]></data>
</project>';
```

Or by creating a new `SimpleXMLElement` with your `$_POST` and converting it to a string, as detailled in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3691036/8863739).